# How does UIActivityViewController select which destination apps to offer for sharing?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an app that shares location information. I'd specifically like to share those locations to [Garmin Drive](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/garmin-speak/id1276198893). In the Garmin Drive plist, it lists gps files as files it accepts with a UTI `com.topografix.gpx`

If I do the simple thing, write a minimal GPX file and add it to the `UIActivityViewController`'s ActivityItems (actually what I'm doing is writing a file with a GPX extension and sharing a URL to that file), I get the intended behaviour: Garmin Drive is in the list of apps and share works. However I also want to share to other apps and built in system services such as messages and email. To do this, I also add a string to the list of items to share.

This works *except...* I also get the GPX file in the message which isn't ideal. To try and return different data to different apps, I've tried various other approaches specifically `UIActivityItemSource` which feels like it [should work](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) and would allow me to only return a gpx for the apps I desire to share the file to but, when I add an object implementing `UIActivityItemSource` to the `UIActivityViewController`'s ActivityItems Garmin Drive isn't in the list of apps.

I return `"com.topografix.gpx"` to `dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType` - which is called twice once for share to pasteboard after `itemForActivityType` has been called. Even if I **always** return the UTI for a GPX file

```
    func activityViewController(_: UIActivityViewController,  dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
    return "com.topografix.gpx"
}
```

That means returning the correct data type identifier doesn't work but just sharing a URL to a file with the gpx extension does work.

The documentation for `UIActivityViewController` is woefully poor. That for the promising sounding `UIActivityItemsConfiguration` is [even worse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsconfiguration).

Does anyone know how the activity controller selects which apps are available to as share destinations.

Comment: The correct UTI is "com.apple.dt.document.gpx"